# python3 + pygit: "No module named 'repository'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, gitpython

When using python3 with the `pygit` dependency, I hit an error that says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate.py", line 8, in <module>
    from git         import Repo, NoSuchPathError, InvalidGitRepositoryError
  File "/mnt/c/Users/foo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/git/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from repository import Repository, InvalidRepositoryError
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'repository'
```

If I `find` in site-packages, I find a module called `repository`. What's the deal?

Answer (score 5):

You meant to use a different module called `gitpython`. You'll want to uninstall `pygit` and get `gitpython` instead.

Pro-tip: use a requirements.txt file to lock down your dependencies to prevent this from happening.